# django-zinnia-blog: decorators to mixins

Tags: python, django, zinnia

with django-blog-zinnia I have this older code

```
from zinnia.views.decorators import update_queryset

def qset():
    return BlogEntry.objects.filter(status=2).filter(creation_date__gte=cutoff)
view_blogs = update_queryset(object_list, qset)
```

The problem is update_queryset gives me

```
ImportError at /

No module named decorators
```

It has to do with the move to class based views. so how do I use a mixin to update?

Comment: in your `views` directory, do you have an `__init__.py` and a file called `decorators.py`?

Comment: I have a __init__.py but not decorators.py specifically

Comment: that is the problem. Just update the version of the `zinnia` you are using.

Comment: check this out: https://github.com/jfdsmit/django-blog-zinnia/blob/master/zinnia/views/decorators.py

Comment: Fantomas is the trunk, https://github.com/Fantomas42/django-blog-zinnia/tree/master/zinnia/views

Comment: the link you gave me is outdated